# Mbed Ethernet with serial port error Nucleo F746ZG

Tags: c++, ethernet, can-bus, mbed

I am trying to use the ethernet connection on the Nucleo F746ZG,
But whenever i use the official include of mbed my pins aren't recognized anymore.
Besides that some of the standard commands dont work either like digitalout.
All help is welcome and thanks in advance.

```
#include "EthernetInterface.h"
#include "mbed.h" //Includes a diffent map.
#include <string>

Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);//Selects the type of serial and assigns a name to it.
DigitalOut led1(LED1);//Selects the led.
CAN can1(PD_0, PD_1); <---- // CAN isnt recognized anymore //Sets the pins for the CAN.
```

this is the error i receive:

Error: Identifier "CAN" is undefined in "Nucleo_F746ZG_Ethernet/main.cpp", Line: 7, Col: 2

Comment: What do you mean by "isnt [sic] recognized anymore"? Do you mean you get build errors? Please copy-paste (as text) the full and complete output when building.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest updating to the latest Mbed OS version, I've tested this on Mbed OS 5.10 against the Nucleo-F746ZG and it compiles fine.